# Injecting dependency inisde Worker from other module

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, android-workmanager

I have been struggling with providing dependency on Android workers using the dagger2. I have followed numerous blogs about how I can achieve it but I somehow have missed something that I am not able to build my dependency graph with it. 
The following is the git repo for the complete source code https://github.com/youranshul/Dagger_worker

The issue I am facing is that how can I provide the dependency which is a part of the activity module but the custom work factory is the part of AppModule.

**EDIT 1:**
The link  github.com/google/iosched provided by @Yavor is a little difficult for me to grab the things keeping my basics in dagger in mind. I have actually looked into the [Dagger from google link][4] and built some understanding of how things work with subcomponents. I have implemented the learning into the mentioned git project and found that I could provide all the dependencies to my worker class. I would like to have a review of my changes and know if I need to improve further on it.

Comment: Can you please specify what is the dependency you want to inject and where. I have build the project and only issue was that there was no way to provide: NiData, but with a constructor injection it worked.

Comment: @YavorMitev yes you are correct NiData is something I want to inject. But it works only when it is provided through constructor injection but if I try to provide through activityModule it doesn't work.

Comment: Why would you want such a thing? You need to rely on constructor injection almost everywhare. Also I thinkg that you are not using Dagger right. For example why you try to inject the activity on your own. I would change your design in general. Please check the https://github.com/google/iosched . If you do it like them it will work for you. This is an article from the guy who wrote it. https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/google-i-o-2018-app-architecture-and-testing-f546e37fc7eb

Comment: @YavorMitev Thanks for the link i would have a look and check if that works

Comment: Also if I were you I would forget about the Presenter. You should be using ViewModel and MVVM. And also check how they are using: @ContributesAndroidInjector and every Fragment and Activity is injected by dagger. Also as you can see they are using almost every where a constructor injection. The less code the better.

Comment: @YavorMitev Please have a look into the edits and let me know if you can give your inputs to improve on it further